# Why is a finite surface on a sphere cannot be covered by a single Cartesian coordinate?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry, physics, curves, general-relativity

The infinitesimal line element on the surface of a sphere is given by $$ds^2=r^2(d\theta)^2+r^2\sin^2\theta(d\phi)^2\tag{1}$$ in spherical polar coordinates where the metric tensor is coordinate dependent. However, transforming to Cartesian coordinates, the same line element on the surface of the sphere is given by $$ds^2=(dx)^2+(dy)^2+(dz)^2\tag{2}$$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ so that the metric tensor becomes Euclidean i.e., $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$.

I can intuitively understand that such a transformation lead to local Euclidean coordinates on the sphere but not global. How can I mathematically show that a single Cartesian frame cannot cover a finite region of the  surface of a sphere (or if we try to do so we get non-diagonal entries in the metric tensor)?

I'm a student of physics, and my knowledge of mathematical jargon is limited. So please use minimum jargon if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two expressions for the metric on the sphere you've given are fundamentally different, in a sense more important than the local/global distinction - in fact, the Cartesian description is genuinely global while the spherical one has technical issues at the poles and at $\phi = 0,2\pi$ . The real difference is that $\theta,\phi$ are genuine coordinates on the two-dimensional sphere, while $x,y,z$ are coordinates on the three-dimensional space in which it is embedded. Any choice of $\theta,\phi$ corresponds to a point on the sphere, while only very particular combinations of $x,y,z$ do.

If "local Euclidean coordinates" means coordinates in which $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, there are in fact no local Euclidean coordinates on the sphere, no matter how small you make your domain - any coordinate patch in which the expression for the metric is constant must necessarily be flat, but the sphere is everywhere curved. When we say a general surface/manifold is "locally Euclidean", it's at most in the *topological* sense that we can locally describe it by smooth coordinates (like $\theta,\phi$ in your example) - this puts no constraint on the *geometry*.

Thus there are three possible answers to your question, depending on how you fix it up: either we can't have a global coordinate system because this would make the sphere diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ (which is not true), we can't have a flat coordinate system because the sphere isn't flat (Gauss' Theorema Egregium), or actually, we can have global "Cartesian coordinates", so long as we remember the constraint.

Comment: But with the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$, (see I've edited) the metric on the sphere can be written as $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$. In fact, Eq(1) can be obtained from Eq. (2). Right?

Comment: @SRS: Right, but this kind of constrained map is not what we mean when we talk about coordinates. If you allow this kind of extrinsic description then *any* manifold with *any* metric can have its metric expressed as $ds^2 = dx_1^2 + \ldots + dx_N^2$ for large enough $N$ and some (potentially very ugly) constraint - this is the Nash embedding theorem. For certain things (like computing dot products) this kind of descriptions is useful; but most of the time we prefer genuine coordinates like $\theta,\phi$, since their local freedom corresponds to genuine freedom on the manifold.

Comment: So perhaps "locally Euclidean" only means that I can write (1) as $ds^2=d\xi_1^2+d\xi_2^2$ where $d\xi_1=rd\theta$ and $d\xi_2=r\sin\theta d\phi$ which looks Pythagorean. But this is not a global relation. Am I correct? How does this fit into the fact that one can always choose locally flat coordinates in the neighborhood of a point in a curved space? @Anthony Carapetis

Comment: @SRS: There are not even *local* coordinates $\xi_1,\xi_2$ satisfying those relations, so using the notation $d\xi_i$ there is misleading. I think what you're getting at is that the fact that the metric is diagonal (but not constant) means the coordinates are *orthogonal* (but not orthonormal). Local orthogonal coordinates do always exist, independent of curvature.

If "flat coordinates" means coordinates in which the metric is Cartesian, one can't choose local flat coordinates on a curved space - flat coordinates imply the region of the space they cover is flat.

Comment: In some sense curved spaces have "infinitesimally flat coordinates" - at a single point we can choose a linear transformation making the metric the identity (like your $d\xi_i$); but we can't integrate this to actual flat coordinates on any neighbourhood. If we try the best we can (producing "geodesic normal coordinates"), the deviation from $\delta_{ij}$ grows quadratically as we move further from the special point; so in some sense we have $g_{ij} \to \delta_{ij}$ as the *coordinate domain* shrinks to a point.

Comment: Regarding "locally Euclidean", this usually refers only to the topological or smooth structure; i.e. the existence of local coordinates at all. It doesn't mean metric in these coordinates is Euclidean.